# Ruby basic RSpec test does not pass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm not able to understand why the following Rspec test does not pass -

```
require "rspec"

require_relative "file-to-be-tested"

describe Customer do
    it "is valid with firstname" do
        customer = Customer.new("handy")
        expect(customer).to be_valid
    end
end
```

for the corresponding Class definition -

```
class Customer
    attr_reader :firstname
    def initialize(firstname)
        @firstname = firstname
    end
end
```

these two code snippets are in separate files in the same folder, so when i run    `~rspec <first-filename>` in the terminal, I get the following error -

```
F

Failures:

  1) Customer is valid with firstname
     Failure/Error: expect(customer).to be_valid
       expected #<Customer:0x007f90e50f3110> to respond to `valid?`
     # ./poodr/poodr_rspec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00551 seconds (files took 0.52876 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./poodr/poodr_rspec.rb:6 # Customer is valid with firstname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`be_valid` is an rspec-rails method, but it looks like you're using just straight rspec. you could do something like:

```
require "rspec"

require_relative "file-to-be-tested"

describe Customer do
    it "is valid with firstname" do
        expect { Customer.new('handy') }.to_not raise_error
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the to be_valid test to do? The issue is that the Customer class has no method called valid? which your test is trying to test.

A hack to move your test along if your doing test driven development:

```
class Customer
  def valid?
   true
  end
end
```

You now have a method called valid and your test will pass. Obviously it shouldn't always be true so your next step would be to expand the definition of valid?. What check needs to be done to know if a customer is valid or not?

Comment: i was following a method outlined in the docs - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec/Rails/Matchers#be_valid-instance_method `thing = Thing.new
expect(thing).to be_valid`

Comment: That doc is expecting the class to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base:
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base as a rails model.